# Match words in word-list and count occurances in php

Tags: php

So I have a general text file with some writing in it, it really ranges randomly, but I also have a wordlist that I want to compare it with and count the occurrences of each word that appears in the text file that is on the word list.

For example my word list can be comprised of this:

```
good
bad 
cupid
banana
apple
```

Then I want to compare each of these individual words with my html/text file which may be like this:

> Sometimes I travel to the good places that are good, and never the bad places that are bad. For example I want to visit the heavens and meet a cupid eating an apple. Perhaps I will see mythological creatures eating other fruits like apples, bananas, and other good fruits.

I wish my output to generate how many times each occurrence of the listed words happen. I have a way to do this with a for-loop but I really wish to avoid the for-loop since it will take forever since my real words list is about 10000 words long.

So in this case my output should be (I think) 9 since it counts total occurrences of a word on that list.

Also if there is a way to display which words where matched and how many occurrences, that would be even more helpful.

Comment: Try [preg_match_all](http://us1.php.net/preg_match_all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$words = '...'; // fill these with your stuff
$text = '...';

// split the word list
$expr = explode("\n", $words);
// sanitize the words contained
$expr = array_map(function ($v) { return preg_quote(trim($v)); }, $expr);
// prepare words for use in regex
$expr = '/('. implode('|', $expr) . ')/i'; // remove "i" for case sensitiviy

// matex prepared words against provided text
preg_match_all($expr, $text, $matches);

// calculate result
echo 'Count: ' . count($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all)

```
$text = 'Sometimes I travel to the good places that are good, and never the bad places that are bad. For example I want to visit the heavens and meet a cupid eating an apple. Perhaps I will see mythological creatures eating other fruits like apples, bananas, and other good fruits.';

preg_match_all('/good|bad|cupid|banana|apple/', $text, $matches);

// ECHO OUT NUMBER OF MATCHES
echo sizeof($matches[0]); // 9

// TO SHOW ALL MATCHES
print_r( $matches );
```

Comment: `I wish my output to generate how many times each occurrence of the listed words happen` That means the total count doesn't have to be grouped together. It has to be word by word

Comment: `So in this case my output should be (I think) 9 since it counts total occurrences of a word on that list.`